# Optimizing tables that already have duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Currently I have raw data that is formatted like this

```
             ---------------------------------------------------------------------
            | User           Number           charges        cost     account#   |
            | John Smith    555-555-5555      Rental         $700      12345     |
            | John Smith    555-555-5555      Phone          $100      12345     |
            | Mike Jones    444-444-4444      Late Pay       $50       98765     |
            | John Smith    555-555-5555      Surcharge      $100      12345     |
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is just an example that I threw together, but the setup is close to the same in the aspect that the raw data doesn't have things grouped appropriately. As you can see the breakdown lists John Smith and his info, then jumps to Mike Jones, and then back to John Smith, creating many duplicate entries in the `user`, `number`, and `account#` column. The real data file that I have, is set up in this way, but consists of thousands of rows and 10-20 columns. I've been trying to find a way to break the username and number off into a separate table in which i could create a relationship with the rest of the file in order to help optimize the table. I realize I could do this if I typed in each entry manually, but that would obviously take way to much time and wouldn't be feasible each time one of these data files needs to be uploaded to the database.

Originally I thought I would just create a user name table that would hold the name and number of the user, and for each user I would have an auto incremented key that would link to the rest of the table. The issue I ran into was that in the case of someone like `John Smith` I would have a table that looks like:

```
               --------------------------------------
              | ID        User       Number         |
              | 1        John Smith  555-555-5555   |
              | 2        Mike Jones  444-444-4444   |
              ---------------------------------------
```

And I would have to go in and enter a foreign key of `1` for every instance of his name in the main table:

```
             -----------------------------------------------------
            | ID        Charges        Cost          account#    |
            | 1         Rental         $700          12345       |
            | 1         Phone          $100          12345       | 
            | 2         Late Pay       $50           98765       |
            | 1         Surcharge      $100          12345       |
           --------------------------------------------------------
```

IS there a way to connect the tables without going in and manually entering in `1` every time the charges table has something related to John Smith?

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQL Server? Two very different RDBMSs...

Comment: oops sorry, Didn't realize I clicked the sql-server tag. This is for Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a third table that works as a link between the two.

Using your example, I'd consider doing something like:

user_table

```
   -----------------------------------------
  |    User       Number         acccount# |
  |   John Smith  555-555-5555   12345     |
  |   Mike Jones  444-444-4444   98765     |
  ------------------------------------------
```

order_table

```
     ------------------------------------------
    | Order#        Charges        Cost       |
    | 1             Rental         $700       |
    | 2             Phone          $100       | 
    | 3             Late Pay       $50        |
    | 4             Surcharge      $100       |
     ------------------------------------------
```

user_orders_table

```
     ----------------------------
    | account#        order#    |
    | 12345               1     |
    | 12345               2     | 
    | 98765               3     |
    | 12345               4     |
     ----------------------------
```

Order# would be auto-incremented by your database.  Account number is assumed to be something unique by design, so it could serve as your primary key on the user_table.  And then the user_orders_table would be the means of storing the link between the two tables.

**Update:**

If you need to keep the database managed identifier for the user table, then the example could be adjusted as follows:

user_table

```
   -------------------------------------------------
  | user_uid   User       Number         acccount# |
  | 1          John Smith  555-555-5555   12345    |
  | 2          Mike Jones  444-444-4444   98765    |
  --------------------------------------------------
```

order_table

```
     ------------------------------------------
    | Order#        Charges        Cost       |
    | 1             Rental         $700       |
    | 2             Phone          $100       | 
    | 3             Late Pay       $50        |
    | 4             Surcharge      $100       |
     ------------------------------------------
```

user_orders_table

```
     ----------------------------
    | user_id         order#    |
    | 1               1         |
    | 1               2         | 
    | 2               3         |
    | 1               4         |
     ----------------------------
```

**UPDATE 2**

One way you could implement this would be using a [procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) to do your inserts.  The goal of using the stored procedure would be to implement the steps mentioned in the comments.

Insert new order

```
1.  Check for user

   1.a  User exists, get their id

   1.b  User does not exits.  Insert them and get their id.

2.  Create new order record

3.  Create user_orders record
```

***Please treat this as pseudo code.***

I don't have access to a MySQL database to test this... and it is really just intended to give a little more detailed theoretical example of how to implement.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertOrder(
    IN 
        p_user_name VARCHAR(50), 
        p_user_phone_number VARCHAR(13), 
        p_user_account_number VARCHAR(50),
        p_order_charges VARCHAR(15), 
        p_order_cost MEDINT
)
 BEGIN
    //check for the user in the database. If they exist, get their id.  If they don't, insert them
    IF EXISTS (SELECT user_uid FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE user_name = p_user_name) //user exists... get their uid
        r_user_uid = user_uid;
    ELSE  //user doesn't exist... create the sucker
        INSERT INTO USER_TABLE (user_name, user_phone_number, user_account_number) 
                    VAULES(p_user_name, p_user_phone_number, p_user_account_number); //assuming that user_uid is an auto_incremented value
        r_user_uid = SELECT user_uid FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE user_name = p_user_name;
    END IF
    //insert your order information NOTE:  could be prudent to check if the order exists already... but we will assume it doesn't for the sake of the pseudo code example.
    INSERT INTO ORDER_TABLE (order_charges, order_cost) 
        VALUES (p_order_charges, p_order_cost); --assuming that order number is an auto_incremented value.
        r_order_id = SELECT max(order_number) FROM ORDER_TABLE //assumes the latest entry is the correct one... may not be the most robust way to do this... depending on how this is to be used overall.
    //Now create the user_orders record
    INSERT INTO USER_ORDERS_TABLE (user_id, order_number) VALUES (r_user_uid, r_order_number);
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**
In additional comments, after the original question, you mentioned that there is no real unique data for the user in your data sets.  This can be a real problem for you, in regards to implementing a solution like this.  To have a good table of users, you need a way for the data itself to be unique.  Relying solely on database generated identifiers is not ideal... and not recommended.  For example, if you want to enter

```
User      Number             account#
John Doe  555-555-5555       12345
John Doe  555-444-3333       12345
John Doe  555-555-5555       12345
```

Is this a list of two different users with the same name; or the same user, that has change their phone number?  In order to create a good table of users, you must be able to determine this from your data that you are going to insert.  As such, there would need to be some additional piece to uniquely identify the user.

You may have other data in the remaining columns that you omitted to help with this task... but if not... then creating a user table may not be the best solution for normalizing your data.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I see what you did there, and that does work based on the example I provided, but what about if the account # is not unique. The issue I have is that the real life data is a list of user who work for a company, and their account numbers are all the same. The only unique identifier they have is their phone numbers, but even that will occasionally change month after month. Regardless, I will give you credit for answering the originally example.

Comment: If your account number isn't unique, you can swap it out with another auto-incremented unique value for the user_table... say user_uid.  Then update the user_orders table to user the order_# and the user_uid instead.  The overall idea is to create your two tables and normalize them as you see fit... then create the third table that links the two based on a known relationship, that is also unique.

Comment: In regards to your updated example. Would the `user_id` in the `users_order_table` need to be manually entered?

Comment: No.  In my mind, it would be another value managed by your database of choice.  It would be unique and auto-incremented by the database.  You could make it a manually entered data.. and then have whatever import tool you are using/creating define it... but the database can do that for you... so may as well let it do it :).  The user_orders_table would get updated on every new order.  The flow would be 1.  New order 2. Does user exist (create if no, add order if yes) 3.  Create new entry for user_orders_table.

Comment: I guess thats where I'm getting hung up on. i'm not sure how I would go about getting `user_id` to generate `1,1,2,1`. I realize I could auto increment those values to be `1,2,3,4,`, but the part I'm having issue with is how to get that `1,1,2,1` order. You're borderline my hero right now lol .

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't seem to need to invent an Id column, because the incoming data file already has the account# field, which presumably provides the required unique key for the customers (else how would it be possible to distinguish between two different John Smiths in that file?).

So you need one table (call it Customer or something), with two columns (or more if there is other cusomer data to hold), one column called AccountNum, and one called User. Using the data you show above it will look like:

```
          AccountNum                    User                 
          12345                         John Smith    
          98765                         Mike Jones
```

and a second table (the Charges table):

```
        AccountNum             Charges        Cost       Date
        12345                  Rental         $700       2014-10-23
        12345                  Phone          $100       2014-10-25
        98765                  Late Pay       $50        2014-10-22
        12345                  Surcharge      $100       2014-10-23
```

Then, each time you receive a new data file, read it in line by line, parse the line to extract the account# value, then look in the Customer table to check that value is there in the AccountNum column. If it is, just create a new record in the Charges table, using that account number for the AccountNum colum in the second table. If the account# value isn't in the Customer table, then it's a new customer and you would have to create a new record in that table before adding the data to the Charges table.

Presumably these charges also have a date field as well? That will distinguish between two charges for the same customer for the same amount. I hope that explains things well enough.